# Connection to server times out with SSH and takes down any possible connection to the same server within the working network

Tags: ssh, wifi, google-cloud-platform, timeout, gcloud

After updating and re-initiating `gcloud` and its SSH connections with `gcloud update`, `gcloud init` and then `gcloud compute config-ssh --remove` && `gcloud compute config-ssh`, sometimes and unpredictably  any connection to the server, let's say `ssh hostname` sometimes develops as follows:

The configuration on `vim ~/.ssh/config` regarding Google Cloud Platform is:

```
 20 # Google Compute Engine Section
 21 #
 22 # The following has been auto-generated by "gcloud compute config-ssh"
 23 # to make accessing your Google Compute Engine virtual machines easier.
 24 #
 25 # To remove this blob, run:
 26 #
 27 #   gcloud compute config-ssh --remove
 28 #
 29 # You can also manually remove this blob by deleting everything from
 30 # here until the comment that contains the string "End of Google Compute
 31 # Engine Section".
 32 #
 33 # You should not hand-edit this section, unless you are deleting it.
 34 #
 35 Host hostname
 36     HostName XXX.XXX.XX.XX
 37     IdentityFile /Users/userz/.ssh/google_compute_engine
 38     UserKnownHostsFile=/Users/userz/.ssh/google_compute_known_hosts
 39     HostKeyAlias=compute.1736255031467791084
 40     IdentitiesOnly=yes
 41     CheckHostIP=no
 42
 43 # End of Google Compute Engine Section
```

And the output of `ssh -vvv hostname` is:

```
OpenSSH_7.5p1, OpenSSL 1.0.2l  25 May 2017
debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/userz/.ssh/config
debug1: /Users/userz/.ssh/config line 35: Applying options for hostname
debug1: Reading configuration data /usr/local/etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug2: resolving "XXX.XXX.XX.XX" port 22
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to XXX.XXX.XX.XX [XXX.XXX.XX.XX] port 22.
debug1: connect to address XXX.XXX.XX.XX port 22: Operation timed out
ssh: connect to host XXX.XXX.XX.XX port 22: Operation timed out
```

After that, any connection to the server, even going to the `domain.com`, trying `telnet XXX.XXX.XX.XX 22` or `ping XXX.XXX.XX.XX`results in a timeout from anyone within the local network.

**What can I do to solve this? Or how can I start to debug this one?**

---

System information:

```
$ gcloud -v

Google Cloud SDK 173.0.0
alpha 2017.09.15
beta 2017.09.15
bq 2.0.26
core 2017.09.25
gcloud
gsutil 4.27
```

MacOS Sierra 10.12.6

Comment: Do you experience the same problem when using wired internet connection? When you experience the timeout, are you able to ping or SSH into VM instance using the external IP from another network? Also, are you able to connect to VM instance using [browser or using cloud shell](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/connecting-to-instance#gcetools) when having this issue ? However, based on the information provided it seems like a network issue.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to go for layer by ping the VMs each others (internal ip) if succeed then check if the port is up

```
telnet localhost 22
```

if down check if the sshd service is up

```
service ssh status
```